# How to set dynamically prop to a component in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I have a listitem component which looks like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
// import $ from 'jquery';

class ListItem extends Component {
  render() {
      let message = "";
    return (
         <div className="item  col-xs-4 col-lg-4">
            <div className="thumbnail">
                <img className="group list-group-image" src="http://placehold.it/400x250/000/fff" alt="" />
                <div className="caption">
                    <h4 className="group inner list-group-item-heading">Product title {title}</h4>
                    <p className="group inner list-group-item-text">
                      {message}
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>     
    );
  }
}

export default ListItem;
```

As you see I want to dynamically set the title and the message of the listItem. How do I use an prop like below to set the title and the message?

And here I reuse this component in PageContent.jsx:

```
<ListItem message="tester"></ListItem>
```

How do I give the title and message to its component to set it dynamically?

Comment: Read the basics about JSX and react? (my downvote is in this case that your post shows no research effort, this is one of the basic things with jsx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First pass the values message and title in the props:

```
<ListItem message="hello" title='world'></ListItem>
```

Then use `this.props.message` and `this.props.title` inside ListItem component to access these values.

Like this:

```
class ListItem extends Component {
  render() {

    console.log(this.props.message, this.props.title);

    return (
         <div className="item  col-xs-4 col-lg-4">
            <div className="thumbnail">
                ....
                      Product title {this.props.title}</h4>
                ....
                      {this.props.message}
                ....
            </div>
        </div>     
    );
  }
}
```

I will suggest you to read the **[react doc](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/components-and-props.html)** because this is a very basic part.

**Note:** I think you are using the jquery with react, that is not a good idea we should avoid that.